# Postgresql distinct by priority

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

All duplicates that appear later (ordering by `rational` in this case) should be removed. But the following query doesn't work:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT ON(postcards.id) postcards.id, postcards.title, rational
 FROM
 (
 SELECT postcards.id, postcards.title,
 some_complex_condition as rational
 FROM postcards
 ORDER BY rational
 ) as postcards
```

I hoped that it depends on ordering but it doesn't. Seems need to set some priority on `DISTINCT ON`. Is it possible to do in `Postgresql`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to use columns inside of `distinct on` in `order by`.

```
select distinct on (postcards.id)
    postcards.id, postcards.title, rational
from
(
    select
        postcards.id, postcards.title,
        some_complex_condition as rational
    from postcards
) as postcards
order by postcards.id, rational
```

From [PostgreSQL documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

> The DISTINCT ON expression(s) must match the leftmost ORDER BY
>   expression(s). The ORDER BY clause will normally contain additional
>   expression(s) that determine the desired precedence of rows within
>   each DISTINCT ON group

So the `distinct on` will use recordset ordered by `id, rational` and take first record in recordset for each `id`.